# How to I set up the TPM module to give the correct password to the hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker, tpm

I have bitlocker encryption set up on my system's hard drive. I had a few problems with the computer, and I turned it in for warranty service. It turns out that in the service center they replaced my motherboard, and now I am required to enter the bitlocker recovery key every time I turn on the PC.

Is there any way to "synchronize" the key to the TPM module, so that I will not have to enter the recovery password every boot?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather from this [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732774.aspx), you might be able to disable and re-enable Bitlocker.  Forcing Bitlocker into disabled mode supposedly leaves the drive encrypted, but with the drive master key on the drive protected only by an unencrypted symmetric key.  Enabling Bitlocker again protects the drive master key in the normal way.

Looks like you might be able to [transfer the key material to the new TPM](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprosecurity/thread/d7be2e19-3eb2-4e7f-8d6a-c7f0f5474b93) from the command line if that doesn't work.

Worst case, you have to turn off BitLocker, decrypt the drive, turn it back on and re-encrypt the drive.

Comment: I tried disabling bitlocker - perhaps incorrectly - but it started decrypting my drive. I probably should have transferred they key material to the new TPM. Thanks for the answer!